How to perfrom DM_TABLE_STATUS operation of a device in kernel moudle
I have a kernel code where we used to make ioctl calls as bellow, this used to work with set_fs() and get_fs() for memory allocation required for user_alloc variable. with latest kernel set_fs() and get_fs() is removed. Am looking for alternative functions which can give device information like DM_TABLE_STATUS, DM_TABLE_DEPS, DM_TARGET_MSG in kernel.
filp = filp_open("/dev/mapper/control", O_RDWR, 0);
if(IS_ERR(filp))
{
    pr_err("Failed to open device mapper\n");
    rc = PTR_ERR(filp);

}
rc = filp->f_op->unlocked_ioctl(filp, command, user_alloc);
if (rc < 0)
{
    goto exit;
}


You have to supply the ioctl with a struct dm_ioctl (plus extra bytes depending on call). That structure has to be initialized with version, data_start, data_size and name.
